# How to override existing spring batch classes?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

In spring batch there is such a class `JdbcStepExecutionDao` with the constant GET_LAST_STEP_EXECUTION (this is an sql query) and there is a method `getLastStepExecution(JobInstance JobInstance, String stepName)` that executes this query. There is also a `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` class with the `createStepExecutionDao()` method, which creates and returns `JdbcStepExecutionDao`. I need to redefine the `JdbcStepExecutionDao` class with the existing GET_LAST_STEP_EXECUTION constant in it (that is, change the sql query) and the `getLastStepExecution` method, then somehow redefine `JobRepositoryFactoryBean#createStepExecutionDao()` so that it returns my redefined `JdbcStepExecutionDao`.

Please tell me how to do it better, maybe somehow through inheritance or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` and override `createStepExecutionDao` by returning your custom `StepExecutionDao`, or create a `SimpleJobRepository` object and pass your custom `StepExecutionDao` to it via the constructor.

Comment: Mahmoud thanks a lot! if I extend from JobRepositoryFactoryBean, then do I understand correctly that next I have to create and put my custom JobRepositoryFactoryBean bin in my application context?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The simplest way to use custom DAOs is to declare a bean of type `SimpleJobRepository ` and pass the custom DAOs to it at construction time.